# How do small teams do secure backups of source code?

Tags: backup, backup-strategies

First of all, I don't mean version control such as git.

I do use git locally but, I'm trying to determine the best way to do back-ups of source code (as well as other app assets) in case of hardware failure or such.

I was thinking I could set up a script to tar my project folders, and encrypt them with gpg. I would then save the encrypted tar to external hard drives and to 1 or more off-site locations using a service such as amazon drive or dropbox.

Currently, I'm a sole developer so my thinking was that this method should be okay. But I wanted to get some input to make sure I'm doing this the best/most reliable way possible.

If there is a better approach to this that may be more applicable to small teams, then please let me know, as I'm more than happy to do the extra work implementing the approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are much of ways of doing that.

But, if you always work local and you need a simple way of doing that, you may take a look at run scripts if some specific usb device is plugged in.

Meaning that a simple backup script with tar would run if you plug in your specific backup hdd.

Take a look at **udev rules** in linux.

> udev is a generic device manager running as a daemon on a Linux system and listening (via a netlink socket) to uevents the kernel sends out if a new device is initialized or a device is removed from the system. The udev package comes with an extensive set of rules that match against exported values of the event and properties of the discovered device. A matching rule will possibly name and create a device node and run configured programs to set up and configure the device.

Take a look at these posts:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device

&

https://askubuntu.com/questions/401390/running-a-script-on-connecting-usb-device

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to go further, to extend the team or even to keep your code for a while in other words, if you want to be professional, I would go with a scalable and reliable tool designed for this: use a real backup and restore tool and don't use scripts. A lot of people, small (and even not so small) companies are doing it and they end up in trouble: maintenance, scalabolity, update, and so on.

There are plenty of backup & restore tools for different purposes and/or platforms, prices and so on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software would be a good start :)

Cheers

Werlan